# golang: how to debug possible race condition

Tags: go, race-condition

I wrote a log collector program in go, which runs a bunch of goroutines as follow:

1. routine A runs HTTP server, allow users to view log information
2. routine B runs UDP server, allow log messages to be sent to it from LAN
3. routine C runs a timer, which periodically query/download zipped log archives from an internal HTTP file server (not part of the program)
4. routine B & C both send processed messages to a Channel
5. routine D runs a for {} loop with a select statement which receives message from the Channel and flush it to disk
6. there are a few other go routines such as a routine to scan the log archives generated by routine D to create SQLite indices etc.

The program has a problem that after a few hours running, the log viewer http server still works well but there are NO messages coming in either from the UDP or fileserver routines. I know that there are endless log messages sending from various channels, also if I restart the program, it start to process incoming logs again.

I added -race to the compiler, and it indeed find out some problematic code, and I fixed these, but still, problem persists. What's more, although there are racy problems, the old version code running on our production server works well, regardless of the racy code.

My question is, how can I proceed to pinpoint the problem. The following is key loop in my log processing routine:

```
for {
    select {
    case msg := <-logCh:
        logque.Cache(msg)
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
    }
    if time.Since(lastFlush) >= 3 * time.Second {
        logque.Flush()
        lastFlush = time.Now()
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at a stack trace when the server stops working and see where each goroutine is blocked.

Comment: how to view stack trace while the program is running seemly well? Note that nothing is apparently wrong, just that the timer routine is not printing message while it is triggered, and UDP server stops receiving messages, and nothing was output on the console

Comment: You could send a SIGQUIT to exit with a stack trace, setup an http handler or signal handler to print one on demand, use the pprof goroutine endpoint, etc. Your goruotines are blocked for some reason, so you want to see why.

Comment: also, if there is a way to view trace of a live goroutine, how do I point out the problem? i.e. from the stack trace, what signifies a blocking problem? The trace will explicitly tell me that a routine is in "blocked" state?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the code that created the blocking.  In the following code:

```
for {
    select {
    case msg := <-logCh:
        logque.Cache(msg)
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
    }
    if time.Since(lastFlush) >= 3 * time.Second {
        logque.Flush()
        lastFlush = time.Now()
    }
}
```

Inside logque.Flush() there are some code that generate log messages which in turn write into the channel, eventually caused the channel's buffer being filled up.  This only occurs when I turn on debug mode, production code does not do this in the Flush() method.

To answer my own question, the method I used to nail down the problem is pretty simple:

```
if len(logch) >= LOG_CHANNEL_CAP {
    //drop the message or store it into
    //secondary buffer...
    return
}
logch <- msg
```

Comment: although the problem is solved, I am still interested how to find out  reason of blocking in a black-box manner.  As @JimB proposed, to break a piece of running code, and inspect its stack trace information, is that possible?